# Laravel Route using array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
Route::post('posts/changeStatus', array('as' => 'changeStatus', 'uses' => 'PostsController@changeStatus'));
```

The code provided is a route from my laravel project. I did not write this code and I am attempting to understand what they have done. I cannot find anywhere in the documentation the reason for using the key value store with 'as' and 'uses'. I would normally write the code below, however this is not working with the ajax-crud setup.

```
Route::post('posts/changeStatus', 'PostsController@changeStatus');
```

Comment: it is used for named routes

Comment: these are named routes, https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes

Comment: You can write `Route::post('posts/changeStatus', 'PostsController@changeStatus')->name('changeStatus')` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes):

> Named routes allow you to conveniently generate URLs or redirects for a specific route. You may specify a name for a route using the `as` array key when defining the route

`as` is the name of that route. You can use it to create an URL with `route('changeStatus')` helper.

`uses` is controller method (action) for the route.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the latest docs 5.5 which did not mention this. Big help.